# How to know if gdb is installed?

Tags: linux, installation, unix, debug, gdb

How can i know if gdb is installed in a unix machine?
I run the following commands:

```
>  gdb 
>  gdb main
```

and the result is

> gdb: command not found

but i don't if this means that gdb is not installed.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. The easiest is to check whether `gdb` is in your `$PATH`:

```
which -a gdb
```

However, the program *could* be installed and not in your user's `$PATH`. To quickly search for an executable called `gdb` do this:

```
locate -eb '\gdb'
```

From `man locate`:

```
NAME
   locate - find files by name


   -b, --basename
          Match only the base name against the specified
          patterns.  This is the  opposite  of  --whole‐
          name.
   -e, --existing
          Print  only entries that refer to files exist‐
          ing at the time locate is run.

EXAMPLES
   To search for a file named exactly NAME (not *NAME*),
   use
          locate -b '\NAME'
   Because \ is a globbing character, this disables  the
   implicit replacement of NAME by *NAME*.
```

Answer (score 1):

That literally means gdb isn't in `$PATH` or is not executable.

But yeah it should be installed to `/usr/bin/gdb` which would be in the PATH and the directory `/etc/gdb` should exist.

Moreover, the usual, which distro are you using?

Comment: Should i have root access to check the above or not? Because i don't...

Comment: No, `ls` should work, however, it's fairly obvious that [most likely] `gdb` isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Type a simple `whereis` comand 
`whereis`  is useful utility to locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command

`whereis -b gdb`
The switch `-b` is for locating the binary

$`whereis -b gdb`
If you get the o/p like this
gdb: `/usr/bin/gdb` /etc/gdb /usr/include/gdb /usr/share/gdb

The most important is the presence in the `/usr/bin/gdb` directory where all executes files are present. If the o/p of `whereis -b gdb` returns null, u need to install `gdb`

Answer (score 0):

from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm)

Run

```
gdb -help
```

If GDB is installed then it will display all the available options within your GDB.

Comment: This will only work if the executable is located in a search path.